# How to observe changes in glazedlists in griffon?

Tags: groovy, griffon, glazedlists

I have a griffon 1.5 application with a glazedlist from which i'm  trying to observe changes and bind its size() to a field in the view ..

in my model I have

```
@Bindable timeslotPicks = 0

@Bindable
@PropertyListener (tableChanged) EventList<ProductionLineEntry> table =
        new BasicEventList<ProductionLineEntry>()  ....
```

.. and

```
def tableChanged = {evt->
    println "table Changed ... "
    setTimeslotPicks(table.size())
}
```

Alas my tableChanged event isn't firing  .. How can I bind a view field to the current size of my glazedlist ?   Thanks in advance  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rejigged my model  ..

```
EventList<ProductionLineEntry> table =
        new BasicEventList<ProductionLineEntry>()
...
```

and removed my tablechanged check    ..

In my mvcInit controller method I added ..

```
 // Add a listener to my list ..
    model.table.addListEventListener(
       {e-> model.timeslotPicks = model.table.size()} as ListEventListener
    )
```

It now works beautifully  ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're observing changes made to the `table` field, and not the contents of the `table` field as you expect. In other words, the code you've written (the `tableChanged` closure) reacts when `bean.table` is updated, for example, when a new `EventList` is assigned to that field.

You must write a `ListChangeListener` in order to adapt list changes to list size.

Comment: I've used a ListEventListener as entries are only ever added or removed - not modified  .. I think i got there eventually  .. Thanks ...